# How to track and analysis android app?

Tags: android, analytics

I want to know what kind of users are using my app.

I think I need the device id, the network type, the network provider name and its ip address. is there any framework to do this thing? And of course I will ask user to enable it before I can do it and leave an option to disable it when user want to toggle it off.

Comment: Please do post the name of your app, so I know that have to avoid it. Ever heard of privacy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a service like [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) or [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/mobileAppsTracking.html) to gather some of this data (not sure about device ID or IP address), but as others have said, you might want to make this "opt-in" via an application preference due to privacy concerns.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this relatively easy by reading this information in your app programatically and then send it to you per sms, email, or just upload it to a server.

However, I don't think that the users will be very lucky that you're doing this. At least you have to inform them about that.

For a ID you could use this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29

To get the IP you could use this code:

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

To get the network type (I think your talking about wifi or mobile) you can use this code snippet:

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//mobile
State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();

//wifi
State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
```

and then use it like that:

```
if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //mobile
} else if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //wifi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to roll your own solution, there are plenty of free, off-the-shelf solutions which work and will let you focus on your app.  I also recommend staying away from web analytics solutions because the application model is different so shoe-horning a mobile app into it can be strange.  You don't think of your app as page views and referrals, do you?

[Localytics](http://www.localytics.com) is one solution: the service is free, the [SDK is open source](http://wiki.localytics.com), and the turnaround time is instant so integration can be done and verified in 10 minutes.

[Disclaimer: this is my site]

Answer (score 0):

Google has a full SDK for this very purpose. Documentation and details are available at:
http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/

From the page:

> The Google Analytics for Mobile Apps
>   SDKs provide an interface for tracking
>   activity within mobile apps and
>   reporting that activity via the
>   standard Google Analytics dashboard.
>
> Tracking mobile applications has some
>   structural variations from tracking
>   website pages. For that reason, you
>   should be familiar with Analytics
>   tracking in order to understand how
>   this SDK works.
>
> Use the SDK to track two basic types
>   of user interaction:
>
> Pageviews - This is the standard unit of
>   measure for a traditional web site,
>   and is used to calculate visits,
>   session length, and bounce rate. We
>   recommend that you trigger at least
>   one pageview at application load to
>   track unique visitors. Because mobile
>   apps don't contain HTML pages, you
>   must decide when (and how often) to
>   trigger a pageview request, and choose
>   descriptive names for reporting
>   purposes. The names you choose will be
>   populated in your Analytics reports as
>   page paths in the Content reports,
>   even though they are not actually HTML
>   pages.
>
> Events - You can define additional
>   events to be reported in the Event
>   Tracking section of Google Analytics.
>   Events are grouped using categories
>   and may also use per-event labels,
>   which provides flexibility in
>   reporting. For example, a multimedia
>   app could could have play/stop/pause
>   actions for its video category and
>   assign a label for each video name.
>   The Google Analytics reports would
>   then aggregate events for all events
>   tagged with the video category. For
>   more information on Event Tracking,
>   see the Event Tracking Guide